# I want to save a file in php

Tags: php

I want to save a file with the date value. For example, 3/10/2010.text. My code is not working. Can someone suggest me something better? Here is my php code:

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $date = $_POST['data'];
    $text = $_POST['textdata'];

    file_put_contents($date.text, $text);
}
```

Comment: The filename `date.text` must be a string.  `file_put_contents("$date.text", $text);` However this code is EXTREMELY DANGEROUS!!! You are allowing end users to save any filename with any contents on your server that the web server user has write access to.

Comment: thank u... but it gives me an error when i submit my text.....Warning: file_put_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory...because im a begginer what should i do?

Comment: If you are trying to save a file named `3/10/2010.text`, the filesystem will interpret that as 3 _directories_ because of the `/`.If those directories don't exist, it won't be able to write them.

Comment: what if i use . instead of / ? or the only way is only the numbers?

Comment: `.` instead of `/` will cause it to write a single file, and it will succeed _if_ the web server has permission to write to the directory you are trying to write in. There's a lot to understand here.

Answer (score 0):

`use quotes`
look for [example here](http://php.net/file_put_contents)